# Erase rows from a cell array depending on empty cells in each row

Tags: string, matlab, delete-row, cell-array

I have a cell array with 8 columns. Sometimes, in the last 5 columns I obtain this: [ ] (empty cell). In case it happens I want to completely erase that row. For instance:

```
19970101 18659 183 '19980820' '00018659' 'RUNYON L' '00001534' 'MERRILL'
19970101 18290 183 '19981221' '00018290' 'MANTON S' '00001534' 'MERRILL'
19970101 835   183    [ ]        [ ]        [ ]        [ ]        [ ]
19970101 10280 183 '19980819' '00010280' 'BRENNAN S' '00001534' 'MERRILL'
```

What I would like to get:

```
19970101 18659 183 '19980820' '00018659' 'RUNYON L' '00001534' 'MERRILL'
19970101 18290 183 '19981221' '00018290' 'MANTON S' '00001534' 'MERRILL'
19970101 10280 183 '19980819' '00010280' 'BRENNAN S' '00001534' 'MERRILL'
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `input_cellarray` to be the input cell array, try this -

```
input_cellarray(all(cellfun(@numel,input_cellarray),2),:)
```

If you want that we must remove rows where exactly the last 5 columns have empty cells `[]`, then you need to tweak the code a bit -

```
input_cellarray(any(cellfun(@numel,input_cellarray(:,end-4:end)),2),:)
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much, I was having a lot of difficulties because I was not dealing with numbers. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user3557054 Awesome! Good to know it worked for you and you are right, cell arrays could be complicated at times.

Comment: By any chance do you know how can I delete/erase the rows that are repeated, I mean the rows that are exactly equal I want to eliminate and only keep the first one. Thank you!

Comment: @user3557054 I think it would be best to post that as a separate question as it looks totally different.

Comment: I will do so, first thing tomorrow! Thanks :)